# Google maps link is opening in webview and not in app

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, webview

I have made an android app in WebView. When I open a Google maps link, it's opening in WebView and not in the Google app. How can I fix this? I have searched on Google and on Stack Overflow but can't find the any solution.

Code:

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {

 private WebView webView;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.mywebsite.nl/");
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: post your code here!!!

Comment: Can you please your whole code here?